# Incorrect resolution while nunning app in android emulator LibGDX

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Making an app with 1280 x 720 resolution using LibGDX.

```
config.height = 720;
config.width = 1280;
```

Works well on desktop launcher even with resize. When i'm running it on android emulator with 1920 x 1080 resolution, the app becomes uncomplete. How to scale it for any resolutions on android emulators?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to use is viewports with your orthographic camera.

There are five viewports.

Extend Viewport , Fit viewport , Fill Viewport , stretch viewport , screen viewport.

If you want fill the whole screen without any worries about aspect ratio you can use fill or extend .

Otherwise you should use fit viewport but some black bars may appear on screen to maintain aspect ratio.

On how to use ports https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports this link can be useful.